# Excel datetime with offset to C# DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimeoffset

I have an excel sheet with a date I get out using some JavaScript or VBA (doesn't matter).

Then I end up having a date that looks like this: `"Tue Feb 4 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2014"`

Are there any build in versions to convert this to C# DateTime? As you can see then I don't use the time part, and thus also don't care about the UTC offset.

Comment: have you tried [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are there any build in versions to convert this to C# DateTime?

Sure! You can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact.aspx) methods to parse your string.

```
string s = "Tue Feb 4 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2014";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss 'UTC+0100' yyyy", 
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
}
```

### But don't use this way when your string have [offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) values.

In [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) page; if your string has signed offset, using [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is recommended.

> With `DateTime` values, the ["zzz" custom format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#zzzSpecifier) specifier represents the
>   signed offset of the local operating system's time zone from UTC,
>   measured in hours and minutes. **It does not reflect the value of an
>   instance's DateTime.Kind property. For this reason, the "zzz" format
>   specifier is not recommended for use with DateTime values.**
>
> With `DateTimeOffset` values, this format specifier represents the
>   `DateTimeOffset` value's offset from UTC in hours and minutes.

```
string s = "Tue Feb 4 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2014";
DateTimeOffset dto;
if(DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(s, "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss 'UTC'zzz yyyy", 
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                DateTimeStyles.None, out dto))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dto);
}
```

Then you can [convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb546101%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) this `DateTimeOffset` to `DateTime`. Because a `DateTime` doesn't store any offset value. There is no such a thing like; *"a `DateTime` with an offset as 1 hour"*

Comment: Thank you. That works. I had tried parse and Convert.ToDateTime.

Comment: This will not work if the UTC part is different like `UTC+0200`

Comment: @user2711965 I think you pointing `DateTime` parsing, right? You are right about that, that's why I suggest `DateTimeOffset` parsing and [`zzz` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#zzzSpecifier) will work on all cases.

Comment: @Habib Yeah, we all are `DateTime` parsing guys :)